# Next.js - import server-side package in a file contains both server-side and client-side functionality?

Tags: next.js

Let's say I have a file named utils.js, containing two functions s and c.
s is a server-side function (Being called on an /api endpoint handler), and uses mongodb package.
c is a client-side function (will be bundled and sent to the browser).

When compiling the app using next build, will it cause any issues?
Does webpack know to bundle only part of a file/module? (considering server-side functions and imports as a "dead code" since they only being called from a server-side code)

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to know which functions get bundled to the client & which ones to the server, there's an easy way to know this → https://next-code-elimination.now.sh/

Just copy & paste the contents of your file into it & you'll see which code gets bundled to the client & which code is bundled to the server. If you have imports then make sure to put all the imports in one file so you can see how it works.

The thumb rule is:

Anything like `getServerSideProps`, `getStaticProps` & `getStaticPaths`  will be removed from the bundled code. If you import anything from a file that uses server-side code like `fs` but doesn't use it in any of the above 3 functions, then it won't be removed (check at Next Code Elimination Tool) & will give you an error.

The tool is the answer. I copy-pasted my file in it & found the answer in an instant.

Comment: Thanks! Just to make sure I understand it right, If I import a function and call it from within a client code (lets say from react component's render function), and in this function file there are 2 more functions there are never being called from client side code, they will not be bundled and sent to the client right?

Comment: @user3343396 Yes, I think it won't be bundled because it's dead code as `Next.js` uses `webpack` underhood. Although, I think you can cross-check it by doing it yourself. Just make a sample app & try doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I think there will be errors but not in the build time. It is likely issues will happen in the run time. You won't be able to access file systems on the client side just like how you can't access the `window` object on the server-side.

In my current project, we have utility functions for both the server-side, client-side, or universal. All server-side functions are called in `getServerSideProps` to make sure they work as expected. All your server-side code in `getServerSideProps` will not be imported as part of the client-side bundle if that's what you mean by "dead code". According to the Next.js

> Note: You can import modules in top-level scope for use in
> getServerSideProps. Imports used in getServerSideProps will not be
> bundled for the client-side.
>
> This means you can write server-side code directly in
> getServerSideProps. This includes reading from the filesystem or a
> database.

I'm not aware of a way you can ask webpack to bundle part of the file or execute a subset of import statements.

I hope that provides some help.

**Reference:**

[Docs - getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering)

[Custom Webpack Config](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config)

Comment: I've asked about something else. All you've said - I already know. To summarize my question: do a function that never being called from a client-code, will be bunfled and sent to the client?

Comment: A function that is never being called from a client-side can still be bundled and shipped to the browsers. If you don't want it to happen, your best bet will be using dynamic import. You can check if you are running the code in the browser and decide to import it if you are on the server. The server side function will be bundled into a separate chunk. If your loading logic is correct, the chunk for the function will not be loaded into the browser. I hope this answer makes more sense to your question.

Comment: I don't understand why a "dead code" (a function that is never referenced from a client side code) will be bundled and send to the browser. I thought the whole idea is that you can write JS everywhere and call functions both from client and the server, but if a function is not used on client side, why send it to the browser? I really don't understand how it works I guess. So if I want this function not be bundled, I just need to cut and paste it to other file?